# how to delete a file on github (remote)

Tags: git, github

I recently added a repo on `https://github.com/me/myRepo`.
Then locally (on my computer) I removed a file `rm ~/myDir/myFile`
I am trying now to make it disappear on github without success. I did:

```
cd ~/myDir
git rm myFile (I had already remove the file physically)
git add -A
git push
```

But the file is still there...

When I do

```
git commit -a
git push
```

This is not working, I get

```
statquant@euclide:~/.vim$ git commit -a
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   bundle/Align (untracked content)
#   modified:   bundle/Clang_Complete-Pathogen (untracked content)
#   modified:   bundle/Vim-R-plugin (untracked content)
#   modified:   bundle/bash-support.vim (untracked content)
#   modified:   bundle/git (untracked content)
#   modified:   bundle/nerdtree (untracked content)
#   modified:   bundle/perl-support.vim (untracked content)
#   modified:   bundle/snipmate (modified content, untracked content)
#   modified:   bundle/tasklist (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
statquant@euclide:~/.vim$ git push
To https://github.com/statquant/.vim.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/statquant/.vim.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: As stated by the error message, your push was rejected. Do a `git pull` first.

Comment: worked ! thanks mate, I'll accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to commit the deletion before pushing:

```
rm file
git commit -a
git push
```

Comment: Any references for your statement?

Comment: He might have other uncommitted changes besides the deletion. He might not want to commit them at the same time.

Comment: What you suggest did not work I edited my message... not sure why though

Comment: See my comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to commit the changes.

```
$ cd ~/myDir
$ git rm myFile
$ git commit -a -m "Your commit message"
$ git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that you want to remove the file from all of the history on github, [read this](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data). Otherwise, yeah commit the change like everyone else has said.

Answer (score 0):

`git rm <file>`

`git commit -m "deleted a file"`

`git push`

However, the file is still available through the history, e.g.  through a cherry-pick of the commit that put it in the repository in the first place.

For sensitive data, or perhaps code you want to ensure never ever makes its way back into your project, it is recommended to 'rewrite' an entire branch's commit history with `git filter-branch`.

WARNING: this will change the SHA-1 hash of ALL the commits in the branch from the point the (now removed) file was originally added, so you will not be able to easily push and distribute the rewritten branch on top of the original branch.  If it is a very recent commit you are removing, then this approach may not cause a problem for others.

`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <file>' HEAD`

To be able to use options like filter-branch, you should always create, code in, and commit to, your own branch within a repository.